# Rails can't find my .js.erb template

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Using jQuery I call `$.getScript("/airports.js")` from a *mobile* device. The app deals with the request this way…

/app/controllers/**airports_controller.rb** (def index)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.js # index.js.erb
  format.json { render json: @airports }
```

Sadly I get this response from the server…

**Server log:**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template airports/index, 
application/index with  {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:mobile], 
:handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/tom/Documents/14-Utveckling/WhichTerminal/app/views"
):
app/controllers/airports_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

What's wrong? I guess what you want the server to tell you is `:formats => [:js]` instead of `:mobile`. How do I make that happen?

(The .js.erb file is stored in `/app/views/airports/index.js.erb`
For good measure, I put another one called `airports.js` in `/app/assets`.)

Comment: If I call it from a desktop browser it works. Somehow `format.js` doesn't work if the client is defined as `:mobile`.

Comment: I use `:mobile` to deal with html request from mobile devices (see railscast #199).

Comment: are you missing `format.mobile`?

Comment: No that is taken care of automatically. What I do when I detect a request as mobile (checking user agent) is replacing the fact that this is a JS call.